# Нужно ли обособлять «наконец»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Это очень опасно и, пойми уже наконец, он нам очень нужен.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы разобраться, нужно рассмотреть два варианта трактовки слова "наконец":

1) как обстоятельственный член предложения со значением "(тебе) пора" (без запятой);

2) как вводное слово, подчёркивающее резкую форму волеизъявления ( http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=293 ).

Первая трактовка выглядит не вполне убедительно, поскольку присутствует слово "уже" с близким значением, в сочетании с которым синонимичное "наконец" выглядит тавтологично (ср. с повествовательной формой "*он уже наконец понял*" - достаточно одного из двух слов, в зависимости от степени актуальности события). Поэтому естественнее предположить, что "наконец" добавлено к императиву для убедительности и является **вводным** словом, которое нужно отделить **запятой**.

Answer (score 3):

**Это очень опасно и, пойми уже наконец, он нам очень нужен.**

1) ***Наконец***  здесь наречие, нет обособления.

***Уже наконец*** — устойчивое сочетание (усиленный вариант), которое часто применяется:

Когда **уже наконец** расцветут подснежники!  Ничего страшного, не бойтесь вы нас **уже наконец**? Это не на один месяц ― это на всю жизнь! Поймите вы это **уже наконец**!

Кстати, почитайте **уже наконец** Чарльза Диккенса и Уильяма Теккерея! [Татьяна Соломатина. Девять месяцев, или «Комедия женских положений» (2010)]

Соня говорила, что сиделка стоит дорого, что давно собиралась переводить отца в специализированную клинику, где уход, и вот **уже наконец** сейчас все документы будут готовы. [Маша Трауб. Ласточ…ка (2012)]

2) Смысл и грамматика предложения не очень ясны, возможное редактирование:

**Это очень опасно, пойми уже наконец, а он нам очень нужен.**